# Processor cores and number of threads

Tags: java

Looking for new hardware, I read that "The key improvement to the i7-8750H is in its core count: we’re now looking at 6 cores and 12 threads".

1/ Would Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() return 6 or 12?

2/ In this case, is using a 12 threads parallelism a better idea than using a 6 threads parallelism for a simple task of parallelized calculation?

Thanks

Comment: The Java runtime has no idea how many physical cores there are on your system. `availableProcessors` simply returns "the number of processors available to the Java virtual machine." (quoted directly from the doc).

Comment: Six cores would mean you can run 6 concurrent cpu bound tasks. If the tasks aren't strictly CPU bound, then using 12 threads could help. Really depends on the application.

Answer (score 1):

`Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` would return `12` as the amount of available processors for Java. Java doesn't know that there's only 6 physical cores, and it doesn't really care either (Java does do some tricks that depend on the amount of processors, but that's usually single-CPU vs. multicore).

The best way to know if your code will benefit from increasing parallelism is by testing it. You certainly can't calculate any performance improvements based on just the amount of cores.

Comment: There are 12 logical cores in your example. The number of logical cores is the number of physical cores multiplied with the number of threads you can run on each of them. On a Hexacore with 2 Threads per Core this would be 12 logical cores then afaik. 6 logical processors though.

Comment: As a side note, if you're running Java in a VM (eg Docker, cloud etc), the JVM reports the actual processors of the machine, not the VM; so basically that is shared across all JVMs running on it. They are going to fix that in an upcoming Java version. (Not sure which. JDK 10?)